# How to get the longest fasta sequence including all possible switching isoforms of a gene out of isoforms

Tags: rna-seq, blast

1. I am working with RNA-seq data without a reference genome/transcriptome and am instead using a **Trinity *de novo* transcriptome assembly**.
2. I analyzed both isoform and gene expression abundances using RSEM.
3. And got differentially expressed GENES via DESeq2.
   In the next step I want to get fasta sequences of differentially expressed genes to use them in the subsequent BlastX/Blast2Go analyses.

   Considering the fact that my Trinity created assembly is based on isoform id:

   How can I extract the gene sequence out of it? Is that a right thing to combine all the isoforms of a single gene in order to generate the longest possible isoform assembly?

   If so, how can I do it to have a union-exon (combined form of all the exons present in the isoforms of an individual gene) sequence used in my Blast analysis?

   If not, how should I proceed with the data type available?
   Trinity assembled file includes the isoform column as:

   ```
   TRINITY_DN1780_c0_g1_i2 
   TRINITY_DN1780_c0_g1_i1 
   TRINITY_DN1780_c0_g1_i3 
   TRINITY_DN1780_c0_g1_i4 
   TRINITY_DN1780_c0_g1_i5
   ```

   and the DESeq2 produces the output (gene differentials) as:

   ```
   TRINITY_DN1780_c1_g1
   ```

Answer (score 2):

From your question it isn't clear if you are trying to identify the isoforms that have a very high or very low differential expression value, or if you are trying to correctly find an orthlog for your top hits using BLAST.

If your question is about isoform-level quantification, [identifying DE at the isoform level is challenging and DESeq2 is only designed for gene-level analyses.](https://support.bioconductor.org/p/43395/#43400) That is why it is only outputting genes rather than a specific isoform.

Comment: Many thanks for your quick reply. I attempt to identify all possible differentially expressed transcripts (resulted from comparing the samples of tw) by Blast or Blast2Go approaches (since I have no reference genome/transcriptome in hand). If at gene level, my first problem is that I can't get the fasta files of gene level (DESeq2 output) from Trinity fasta file. Is there any automated software/command to get gene level sequence from Trinity fasta file? 2. If not, my second problem is that which procedure should I follow to analyze my data at isoform level (preferably for those with high diffe

Comment: So, just to be clear - your final goal is to find the specific isoforms with the highest differential expression from your transcriptome?

Answer (score 2):

There's no clear way to go from a trinity "gene" (this is just a cluster of isoforms with shared sequence) to a linear gene sequence that will be blastable and not cause a number of headaches (e.g., due to swapping the order of exons).

What I would suggest that you do is either Blast2GO the isoforms within the Trinity-defined "genes" or take the highest expressed isoform within a "gene" as the sequence you feed into Blast2GO for that gene. Alternatively just use isoforms for everything and avoid this whole issue.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of questions in this post, and the main ones have been answered.  Here is an answer to the one that has not been answered yet:

**How can I do it to have a union-exon (combined form of all the exons present in the isoforms of an individual gene) sequence used in my Blast analysis?**

I don't think you should do this, but if you want one of the usually many plausible linearized representations of transcript isoforms, then [Lace](https://github.com/Oshlack/Lace) would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

It appears from the comment in another question that this question is also about transcript-level differential expression analysis.

If instead of using RSEM you use [kallisto](https://pachterlab.github.io/kallisto/about) for transcript quantification, then you could use [sleuth](https://pachterlab.github.io/sleuth/about) to perform transcript-level differential expression analysis.